# Get list of objects of users who reacted to a message with certain emoji in Discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, javascript-objects

Below is a code snippet of a Discord bot written in Discord.js:

```
client.channels.fetch('channelID here').then(function (channel) {
 channel.messages.fetch('messageID here').then(function (message) {
  console.log(message.reactions.cache.get('EmojiID here').users);
 });
});
```

It gets the following output in console:

```
ReactionUserManager {
  cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
  cache: Collection [Map] {},
  reaction: MessageReaction {
    message: Message {
      channel: [TextChannel],
      deleted: false,
      id: 'MessageID here',
      type: 'DEFAULT',
      system: false,
      content: 'What role do you want?\n' +
        'React with:\n' +
        '<:Red:870224025811558450>  for <@&870162738561814578> \n' +
        '<:Blue:870224213976444959> for <@&870162842983206922> \n' +
        '<:Yellow:870224106061172776> for <@&870162885412810773>\n' +
        'You will be assigned the role corresponding to your most recent reaction.\n' +
        'Unreact to remove the role.',
      author: [User],
      pinned: false,
      tts: false,
      nonce: null,
      embeds: [],
      attachments: Collection [Map] {},
      createdTimestamp: 1627548937713,
      editedTimestamp: 1627617831107,
      reactions: [ReactionManager],
      mentions: [MessageMentions],
      webhookID: null,
      application: null,
      activity: null,
      _edits: [],
      flags: [MessageFlags],
      reference: null
    },
    me: true,
    users: [Circular],
    _emoji: ReactionEmoji {
      animated: undefined,
      name: 'Red',
      id: 'EmojiID here',
      deleted: false,
      reaction: [Circular]
    },
    count: 2
  }
}
```

I can see the `count: 2` in the output. I want to get the list of the objects of those two users. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close. [`ReactionUserManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager) is a manager; it means it has a `cache` property that returns a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of `User` objects.

You could also fetch the users too:

```js
client.channels.fetch('channelID').then(function (channel) {
 channel.messages.fetch('messageID').then(function (message) {
  const reaction = message.reactions.cache.get('EmojiID')
  reaction.users.fetch().then(function (users) {
    console.log(users)
  })
 })
})
```

If you can use async-await (i.e. you're in an async function), you can make it more readable:

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch('channelID')
const message = await channel.messages.fetch('messageID')
const reaction = message.reactions.cache.get('EmojiID')
const users = await reaction.users.fetch()

console.log(users)

// e.g. add a role to each user
users.each(async (user) => {
  // get the member object as users don't have roles
  const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(user.id)
  member.roles.add('ROLE ID')
})
```

Comment: I tried this with the `.cache` property even before posting this. I tried it again, and this is the output:
`Collection [Map] {}`

Comment: Yes, I told you you were close. Isn't a collection what you wanted? A collection is a list of objects. I also added a link so you can check what methods a collection has. What do you want to do with that list?

Comment: I want to assign those users with a role. And, I don't know how to use a collection. I am new to js.

Comment: By the way, isn't this map `Collection [Map] {}` empty?

It is supposed to contain two users.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought you just removed its content :) Empty collections usually look like `Collection(0) [Map] {}`. Anyway, I'll update my answer in a minute to fetch the users too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your answer perfectly does what I intended.

Comment: One change you can make to your answer is to put the `const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
  member.roles.add('ROLE ID')` inside `if (!user.bot) {}`

Comment: Or you could use a filter like `users.filter(user => !user.bot).each(/* the same */)`

Comment: this solution was working fine. but now, it give the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined` in the line `member.roles.add('ROLE ID')` Why is this?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, added `fetch` there too.

Comment: Please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607953/discord-js-continue-loop-for-next-users-from-reaction-users-fetch-eachuser